# Python JSON decode ValueError: Extra data:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem trying to decode and print JSON I receive from a socket connection.

The full traceback:

```
C:\Users\Jeremy>python F:\Files\Python\test.py
2013-01-04 21:15:35 [INFO] [AutoSaveWorld] World save Complete!
2013-01-04 21:15:50 [INFO] [←[34;1mMain←[37;1m]←[32;22mRexOZ←[37;1m: you cahaned
 your house it looks awesome←[m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Files\Its safer indoors\Python\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = json.loads(dreceve)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 309, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 151 - 344)
```

As you can see the first 2 lines print fine and then it crashes.

Full code:

```
import socket
import json
import re

HOST = 'host.host.net'
PORT = 8082
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
dsend = "/api/subscribe?source=console&key=SUPERSEXYSECRETEY&show_previous=true\n"
s.sendall(dsend.encode())

while 1:
    dreceve = s.recv(1024).decode()
    data = json.loads(dreceve)
    succses = data['success']
    line = succses['line']
    print(line)

s.close()
```

I have goggled around for this error and the pages I found did not solve my problem, any help work be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to show sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use raw sockets?

Comment: @BrenBarn https://github.com/alecgorge/jsonapi/wiki/How-to-use-the-stream-api-over-a-socket-connection (bottom of the page)

Comment: @miku No, I'm open to any working suggestions.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you're just reading chunks of 1024 bytes.  The socket may send a chunk that is only a JSON fragment and not valid JSON in itself.  You should try some other way to get the data (like those suggested by miku).

Comment: -1 for using raw sockets instead of using a decent module for fetching URLs.

Comment: @AndreasJung Really? Maybe if the question was bad or he displayed gross ignorance, but down-voting because he doesn't use "a decent module"? That's petty.

Answer (score 9):

Whatever you receive, it does not seem to end where it should end; example:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(""" {"Hello" : "World"} \ """)
....
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 21 - line 1 column 23 (char 21 - 23)
```

I'd suggest inspect your output before it gets parsed to get hold of the problem.

PS. There are simpler ways to get JSON data from a server (assuming your server returns parsable JSON, which it might not). Here is an example using the [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library:

```
>>> import json, requests
>>> u = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?alt=json"
>>> json.loads(requests.get(u).text) # <-- request + parse
{u'feed': {u'category': [{u'term': u'http://gdata.youtube.com/...
```

.....

Answer (score 3):

In the json lib ->decoder.py->decode function

```
if end != len(s):
       raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data" , s , end , len(s)))
```

It's mean if your string's len != end , will raise this Exception
And the end is the last "}" postion in your string.
so you I can use:

```
string = "".join([string.rsplit("}" , 1)[0] , "}"])
```

cut the extra data after the last "}".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there may be ';' at tail of the JSON string. Just remove it:

```
json.loads(string.strip(';'))
```